# How can I not show profile pics in Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I don't want any profile pics to appear for any contacts in Whatsapp on my HTC One X, any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Until and unless the app doesn't provide the functionality there is nothing an end use can do except request them for the feature.

One difficult and less possible way though would be to monitor the data transfer whatsapp makes and see if it uses different subdomain or IP for pictures like pics.whatsapp.com. If they do so then you can block that particular subdomain. But this might cause the app to misbehave.